# Using Bluetooth 4.0/LE verses RF

Tags: rf, wireless, bluetooth, remote-control, bluetooth-low-energy

I am asking this question in hopes to get a solid answer from anyone who has direct experience dealing with the most recent RF as well as Bluetooth 4.0/LE developments.

What I am essentially trying to understand is why so many devices such as keyboards, mice and remote controls seem to always opt for using RF verses using Bluetooth.

More specifically - my understanding is that the new 4.0 specs of Bluetooth and the LE (low energy) variations would be the ideal protocol to use while not requiring a dongle.

My thought was that there must be something I am not aware of which you electrical/RF engineers do know.

In my view these reasons my be related to one or more of the following:

- RF interference
- Higher battery usage
- Increase Latency
- Company Policy decisions (like with Logitech that seems to always force the use of their own dongle)

Can someone enlighten me on the pros/cons based on their direct experience using both. Please provide any supporting facts to convince me that Bluetooth 4.0 or Bluetooth LE is the wrong wireless protocol to use for example as the wireless technology for a small handheld (apple style) remote control which does not need to be charged every week (other than the distance factor)?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to ask... BLE is Bluetooth 4.0, it is an RF communication standard

Comment: I'd choose simple RF transceivers over Bluetooth because Bluetooth modules generally cost more.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth LE is a licensed technology. You have to pay to create and sell a BLE compatible device. As such, it could be cheaper to use either a unlicensed off the shelf RF technology or roll you own.
[BLE 'qualification & listing' Fees](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/test-qualification/qualification-overview/fees).

Comment: I was under the impression that if you buy a BLE module, all those costs were already paid by the module manufacturer? (and maybe incorporated into the price you are paying the module)

Comment: @PaduMerloti Correct -- if you are just buying a module, like the [Bluegiga BLE113](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble113-bluetooth--smart-module/), you just pay for the module.  Furthermore, if the module (like this one) has an integrated antenna and is FCC certified as a whole, you usually don't have to pay for additional FCC testing which is an issue if you connect your own device with a separate antenna.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be under the impression that 'RF' is some kind of protocol.

It is not, it is just a shorthand for "radio frequency".

BLE has defined standard for things like pairing, which might not match what the wireless keyboard makers have in mind for their user experience.

BLE has favorable power consumption, so that's not the reason.

BLE is also a newer standard, and some of the wireless designs are actually pretty old.  So they haven't been updated yet.  When it becomes so popular that keyboards won't need to include the dongle, I expect you'll see a lot switching  to BLE.

I discuss BLE more in this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19630/

Comment: Hi @markrages, the link doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think cost of compliance with standards might be another reason. Like markrages said RF is no specific protocol. If I wanted to make a low cost device right now, there are many cheap ways to use radio frequency in a "wild west" fashion to send the data. To use Bluetooth or BLE would require me to meet many criteria that I might not be concerned with. Not only would this incur development cost of meeting the standard, but there is likely administrative costs involved with getting a product Bluetooth certified as well.